# Why isn't my IF Formula working when it comes to blank cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I am using the following `IF` formula:

```
=IF(AH132<>"",DAYS(TODAY(),AH132),"")
```

But when it comes to a blank reference cell, the formula is still adding a value when it should not and I am wondering how to fix it or make it work.

Comment: Apparently the cell is not sufficiently blank. Maybe it has a space? Or a zero with a zero-suppressing format string?

Comment: The cell has a formula in it, could it be possible that it is recognizing the formula in the cell as a value? If so, is there a way to get it to ignore the formula in the cell?

Comment: If the formula returns `""`, your formula will detect it correctly.

Comment: You were right about the zero with a zero-suppressing format string. That was the issue! thanks for the help, this was driving me nuts